# How to enable servlet in GWT project

Tags: gwt

I created one GWT webapplication project.Inthat i want to create servlet program,but in that project not allow to create servlet program.How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs? http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html

It's all there. Using Eclipse and Google Eclipse Plugin should help too :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, I think you should precise exactly what you want to do.

Anyway, GWT does not prevent you from coding a classical servlet.

A servlet is part of Java server side technology. So as long as your are using a servlet container (Tomcat, Glassfish, Jetty etc.) for the server you can use a servlet in your project.

To do so create your servlet class and declare it in your web.xml. You can find many tutorials like this one that will explain to you how to do this : [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/index.html)

From your GWT client you can call your servlet using a `RequestBuilder` [requestBuilder javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html)